# Access denied for user root@localhost

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I've installed Laravel 9 and now, when I go to the login page I get this error below. In the older version of Laravel I could connect to the local database (xampp).

I don't know why Laravel 9 doesn't connect. I've cleared the cache yet it's still not working. The database doesn't have any password and the user name is `root`.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Please anybody help me with us.

Comment: You forgot to fill out your `.env` file. `root@localhost` is the default value for `DB_USER` and `DB_HOST`.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-1RaAE3VsI

Comment: I already set it but not working, I face the problem with new laravel version.

Answer (score 0):

go to .env file fill the following lines :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: I already set it but not working, I face the problem with new laravel version.